# WooCommerce - Issue hiding billing fields for free products

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm trying to hide the billing fields on checkout (woocommerce) for free products. I have come across this PHP code which seems to work:

```
function patricks_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    // if the total is more than 0 then we still need the fields
    if ( 0 != $woocommerce->cart->total ) {
        return $fields;
    }
    // return the regular billing fields if we need shipping fields
    if ( $woocommerce->cart->needs_shipping() ) {
        return $fields;
    }
    //we don't need the billing fields so empty all of them except the email
    unset( $fields['billing_country'] );
    unset( $fields['billing_last_name'] );
    unset( $fields['billing_company'] );
    unset( $fields['billing_address_1'] );
    unset( $fields['billing_address_2'] );
    unset( $fields['billing_city'] );
    unset( $fields['billing_state'] );
    unset( $fields['billing_postcode'] );
    unset( $fields['billing_phone'] );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'patricks_billing_fields', 20 );
```

However, while the form text is removed from the fields, the field styling still remains:

[image: attached screenshot]

This CSS I used to style form fields (globally) is:

```
form .input-text {
       background: #f9f6f8;
       background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left           bottom,from(#f9f6f8),to(#fff));
       background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f9f6f8,#fff);
       background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top,#f9f6f8 0,#fff 100%);
       background: -moz-gradient(center top,#f9f6f8 0,#fff 100%);
       filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,  startColorstr=#f9f6f8, endColorstr=#ffffff);
       -ms-filter:  "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#f9f6f8,  endColorstr=#ffffff)";
       box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
       -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
       -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
       -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
       border: 1px solid #d7d4d6;
       outline: 0;
       line-height: 1em;
}
```

I have checked for similar threads but can't seem to find an answer.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: **I have tested your code, and I don't get this problem.** This is certainly specifically related to your theme. This issue could come from custom templates located in the woocommerce folder of your main theme or/and in your child theme. It can be also some hooked custom function of your theme.